# Manipulating value by using subscribe method in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, zip, subscribe

I use angular 6

I listen to 2 forms via 2 [formControl] "toppings":array and "toppings2":array.

My code works well when I listen to one or the other but when I use the operating zip the logs come from one form or the other randomly.

I do not know how to manipulate val to get the expected result

My code:

```
ngOnInit() {

zip(this.toppings.valueChanges, this.toppings2.valueChanges).subscribe(val => 
            console.log(val[0] +val[1]);


}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) example.

Comment: i can try tomorrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [combineLatest](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html) instead of `zip`

> When any observable emits a value, emit the latest value from each.

```
combineLatest(this.form.get('toppings').valueChanges, this.form.get('toppings2').valueChanges)
    .subscribe(val => console.log(val))  // should print both form control values
```

Check this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/conbine-latest-rxjs?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: I must init form ?

Comment: Not actually required. They are just two form controls. It is just an example to show the usage of combineLatest. I used form for the convenience.

Comment: console doesn't know property"form". I must import him ?

Comment: and core.js:1598 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Comment: Please go through the full example in the demo. If you want to get the value through form, then you have to initialize form. If you want to fetch it using form controls, then you have to create instances of those form controls to observe valueChanges.